# RD server and CALs tracking

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop, terminal-server

I have installed a RD server on 2008R2 and activated the server, installed my 3 CALs per users. How can i track which user is using which CALs? Because so far i've only found how to to reports and it's telling me i have 3 CAL and $ are used...

thanks

Comment: Uhm why do you think it matters?  A cal is a cal.

Comment: because i did some testing and now i want to put it in prod :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Remote Desktop Licensing Manager. Right-click on the name of the licensing server on the left and pick "Create Report" -> "Create Per User CAL Usage...". Click "Create Report".

In the tree on the left, expand until you get to Reports. Click on that. Then on the right side, you can right-click the report you just made and pick "Save As". Save it somewhere, then open in Notepad or Excel. This will list all of the users that have acquired a TS CAL license and the last time they logged in.

Comment: Awesome and is there a way to revoke these CALs?

Comment: No, but you don't need to because it doesn't matter. The licensing server doesn't actually prevent users from logging in if you go over your count. You use this report during your yearly licensing true-up with Microsoft. By then the users you tested with will automatically have their licenses expired. (I think that's 90 days?)